# Create and remove iFrames using variables

Tags: javascript, html, variables, iframe

I'm working on a project to create a landing page for our pilots to quickly check weather prior to takeoff. Due to our computer security limitations I can only work with iframes to access the information I need.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
function NWSRADAR() { 
   ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
   ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://radar.weather.gov/Conus/Loop/NatLoop.gif"); 
ifrm.setAttribute("id", "NWSRADAR")

   document.body.appendChild(ifrm); 
} 

    function rNWSRADAR() {
   var frame = document.getElementById("NWSRADAR");
        frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
}
```

So the first one opens the frame and the second one closes it. I call the function with a hyperlink like this:

```
<a href='javascript:NWSRADAR()'>NWS Radar</a>
<a href='javascript:rNWSRADAR()'>X</a>
```

This is all good, but I have about 30 links I need to turn into clickable buttons and would like to know how to have one generic open and shut function that uses variables for the webpages instead of having 30 separate functions with fixed iframe sources and names.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use arrays:

```
function NWSRADAR(num) { 

   var urls = ["a url", "another url"];

   ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
   ifrm.setAttribute("src", urls[num]); 
 }
```

And then you'd just call it like this:

```
<a href='javascript:NWSRADAR('number that corresponds with the right url in the array')'>NWS Radar</a>
```

And you could do the same with the names.